# Does a SafeFileHandle change between Open Close and Reopen?

Tags: c#, .net, instance

I am using a SafeFileHandle to talk to USB devices. If I close a Handle and then reopen a handle to the same device (assuming is has not been removed and reattached/enumerated) will the first and second handles necessarily be exactly the same? Or is a handle like an instance thing that can be different every time it's opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just run a quick experiment, using a SafeHandle to a file (based on the sample code in the MSDN [SafeFileHandle class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safefilehandle.aspx)) and it would appear that the handle does indeed change when closed and then opened again.